# Xcode 7 build problems

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, xcode7-beta4

Has anybody experienced cloud storage issues when building to your device using Xcode 7? Interfacing with AWSS3 buckets works fine from my simulator, but doesn't actually work after building to my phone using Xcode 7 beta. It doesn't crash or anything, I just can't load data into my S3 bucket.

CODE BELOW. Feel free to just pick a single implementation (say, delete) and test it out. I have a free developer account and am only using Xcode 7 to build on my device.

```
viewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>

@interface tableTableViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

- (IBAction)cameraRoll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *imageNames;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *imageObjects;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager;


@end
```

ViewController.M

```
@interface UIViewController () {

}

@end

@implementation tableTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self listAllObjects];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)cameraRoll:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *iPhonePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    [iPhonePicker setDelegate:self];

    //UIPopoverController *iPadPicker = [[UIPopoverController alloc]init];

    UIImagePickerController *iPadPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    [iPadPicker setDelegate:self];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            [iPhonePicker allowsEditing];
            [iPhonePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        }
        else {
            [iPhonePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
            [iPhonePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        }

        [self presentViewController:iPhonePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


//    else if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
//        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
//            [iPadPicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
//            [iPadPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
//        }
//        else {
//            [iPadPicker allowsEditing];
//            [iPadPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        //CREATE POPOVER

//        }
}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self.image setImage:image];

    [self uploadImage:info];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });

}



-(void) uploadImage:(NSDictionary*)info {

    imageObject *a = [imageObject new];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSString *imagePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload-image.tmp"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f.jpg", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970 ] ];
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    a.image = image;
    a.key = fileName;
    [self.imageObjects addObject:a];


    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.bucket = @"karanphotos";
    uploadRequest.key = fileName;
    uploadRequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];


    [[self.transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

        if (task.error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is causing error", uploadRequest.key);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Upload successful");
        }
        return nil;
    }];
}


-(void) listAllObjects {

    AWSS3 *S3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
    AWSS3ListObjectsRequest *listObjects = [AWSS3ListObjectsRequest new];
    listObjects.bucket = @"karanphotos";
    self.imageNames = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.imageObjects = [NSMutableArray new];

    [[S3 listObjects:listObjects]continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"listObjects failed-->%@", task.error);
        }
        else {
            AWSS3ListObjectsOutput *output = task.result;

            for (AWSS3Object *temp in output.contents) {

                    imageObject *a = [imageObject new];
                    a.key = temp.key;
                    [self.imageObjects addObject:a];
                }
            }

        [self downloadImages:self.imageObjects];
        return nil;
    }];
}


-(void) downloadImages:(NSMutableArray *)imageNames {
    for (imageObject *a in imageNames) {
        NSString *downloadingFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"downloaded-%@", a.key]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:downloadingFilePath];

        AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *download = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];
        download.bucket = @"karanphotos";
        download.key = a.key;
        download.downloadingFileURL = url;

        [[self.transferManager download:download] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
            if (task.error) {
                if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                    switch (task.error.code) {
                        case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                        case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                            break;
                        default:
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"%@", task.error);
                }
            }

            if (task.result) {
                AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput *downloadOutput = task.result;
                NSLog(@"success");
                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:downloadOutput.body]];
                a.image = image;
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [self.tableView reloadData];
                            });
            }
            return nil;
        }];
    }
}

- (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender {


}





 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     imageObject *a = [self.imageObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     self.image.image = a.image;
     cell.textLabel.text = a.key;
     return cell;
 }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    imageObject *a = [self.imageObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.image.image = a.image;
}


 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }




 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

     imageObject *a = [self.imageObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [self.imageObjects removeObject:a];
     [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest *deleteReqest = [AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest new];
     deleteReqest.bucket = @"karanphotos";
     deleteReqest.key = a.key;

     [self deleteObjectFromBucket:deleteReqest];
 } }


-(void)deleteObjectFromBucket:(AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest *)deleteRequest {

    AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];

    [[s3 deleteObject:deleteRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        if(task.error){
            if(task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled && task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused){
                NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Successfully deleted");
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (self.imageObjects.count == 0) {
                [self.image setImage:nil];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        });

        return nil;
    }];
}


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 }


 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 return YES;
 }


#pragma mark - Navigation

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 }


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.imageObjects.count;
}


@end
```

Comment: You should put the code snippets and steps to reproduce the issue so that others can see if they can reproduce it.

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda will do!